# reactjs - Dropzone for file upload

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do i get the file (full path) while am trying to upload a file in reactjs. Am using react-dropzone component.

```
<Dropzone accept="image/jpeg, image/png, txt/plain"  maxFilesize= "2"  
onDrop={(files) => this.onDrop(files)}>
<div>Try dropping some files here, or click to select files to upload.</div>
</Dropzone>
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score -1):

You have those files as a [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Blob) in `files` variable.

You may [create an object url](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) with that blob. For example;

`const temporaryURL = URL.createObjectURL(files[0]);`. With this, you will have a temporary URL. But it's gonna stay in the memory. So when you don't need that URL anymore, don't forget to revoke it! `URL.revokeObjectURL(temporaryURL);`

Comment: how to append with the file name..?